# mediate function: How to have output by "treated/control"?

Tags: r, mediator

**Problem:** The `mediate` function of the `mediation` package sample code provides a different output for treatment and control groups, but I am not able to reproduce this with my own data.

**Attempted:** I've tried specifying `treat = "Group"`, as well as `control.value = 0` and `treat.value = 1` in the options, changing my Group factor to 0 and 1 dummy codes, removing my third group so to have only two, using `glm()` instead of `lm()`.

**Code:**

```
# Example code from package documentation
require("mediation")
require("sandwich")
data("framing")
med.fit <- lm(emo ~ treat + age + educ + gender + income, data = framing)
out.fit <- glm(cong_mesg ~ emo + treat + age + educ + gender + income, 
               data = framing, family = binomial("probit"))
med.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "treat", mediator = "emo",
                   robustSE = TRUE, sims = 50)
summary(med.out)

# Output (first lines only):
                          Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value    
ACME (control)             0.08070      0.02892         0.14  <2e-16 ***
ACME (treated)             0.08062      0.03015         0.13  <2e-16 ***
ADE (control)              0.00718     -0.08888         0.12    0.96    
ADE (treated)              0.00710     -0.10052         0.13    0.96
```

But for example if I take a different (continuous instead of logistic) dependent variable from the same dataset (`p_harm` instead of `cong_mesg`), the output is not separated by control/treated, and I'm worried I might not get the right per-group interpretation in this case:

```
out.fit <- glm(p_harm ~ emo + treat + age + educ + gender + income, 
              data = framing)
med.out <- mediate(med.fit, out.fit, treat = "treat", mediator = "emo",
                   robustSE = TRUE, sims = 50)
summary(med.out)

# Output (first lines only):
               Estimate 95% CI Lower 95% CI Upper p-value    
ACME             0.5930       0.2056         0.95  <2e-16 ***
ADE             -0.2082      -0.5576         0.07    0.24
```

**Question:** I'm not sure I understand correctly, but is it that the mediate function will only provide output by control/treated IF and only if there's an interaction between the treatment and mediator? How does the interpretation differ in this case?